# What are the ideal conditions for changing oil in a car engine?

Tags: ford, oil-change

I own a Ford Transit Connect 2012 1.8 TDCI and am planning on getting the engine oil changed.

I can decide between two mechanics. The first one is about an hour away. The other one is only about 10 minutes away.

What are the ideal conditions for changing oil in a car engine? Should the engine be warm? [This Q/A](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/68227/should-i-let-the-motor-run-for-a-few-minutes-before-oil-change-even-if-its-b) indicates that the oil drains faster, when the engine is warm, but is there anything else to watch out for?

Comment: I would be more concerned about the quality of oil they refill with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I let the motor run for a few minutes before oil change -- even if it's been in storage for a while?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/68227/should-i-let-the-motor-run-for-a-few-minutes-before-oil-change-even-if-its-b)

Comment: Option 3 is to learn to do it yourself and save the labour charge.  Oil changes aren't generally difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking the distance you have to drive will affect the quality of the oil change. I don't think there's anything to be concerned about either way. The main advantage to changing oil while it's warm is that the heat lowers the oil viscosity, which allows the old oil to drain more quickly, and more thoroughly from small passages. Also, driving and engine vibration will tend to stir up sediments which are otherwise settled in the pan, so more of them will flow out with the old oil.

Once the engine's warm, you've achieved the goal. Driving a longer distance won't make that big a difference in the quality of the oil change.

That said, there will always be some old oil left in the engine no matter what procedure you follow, and the amount of new oil added will be enough to dilute any old oil or impurities significantly.

Replacing old oil with fresh oil is always better than leaving the old oil in place, even if the oil change isn't done under ideal conditions.

The quality of the service provider and the oil they use is a much more important factor to consider than how far you have to drive. A further drive to a shop that engages in shady practices does you no good.

Check reviews for both shops on local forums and review sites to make your decision.

Assuming both shops have reasonable reputations, go to the closer one to save time and gas.